# Match All Foreign Key's Length With Their PK in Oracle

Tags: sql, plsql

as we know PK and FKs type must be same, the size CAN be different in Oracle

1. find all the foreign keys,
2. find all the PK them are referenced to
3. compare the length
4. use the PK's length as standard if FK is short.

anyone got the script?

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to provide you with ready made scripts.

Comment: I have tried various things. a bit of this a bit of that. as this might be a common script in some DBA's tool box already, thats why I asked see if anyone got it.

Comment: If you don't get any decent answers here, you may want to try dba.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @shanyangqu Since you've tried 'various things', please post the code as well as the problems you've encountered with it, and we'd be happy to help you fix those issues.  We're not in the 'do your work for you' line of work.

Comment: @George Stocker who ASKED you doing the script?  if someone got the similar script just post it. if you haven't leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT cc.table_name,
       CC.COLUMN_NAME,
       TCF.DATA_TYPE || '(' || TCF.DATA_PRECISION || ',' || TCF.DATA_SCALE || ')' DTYPE1,
       rcc.table_name AS r_table_name,
       RCC.COLUMN_NAME AS R_COLUMN_NAME,
       TCP.DATA_TYPE || '(' || TCP.DATA_PRECISION || ',' || TCP.DATA_SCALE || ')' DTYPE2,
       cc.position
FROM   user_constraints c
       JOIN user_cons_columns cc ON c.owner = cc.owner AND c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
       JOIN USER_CONS_COLUMNS RCC ON C.OWNER = RCC.OWNER AND C.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = RCC.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND CC.POSITION = RCC.POSITION
       JOIN USER_TAB_COLS TCF ON TCF.TABLE_NAME = CC.TABLE_NAME AND TCF.COLUMN_NAME = CC.COLUMN_NAME
       JOIN USER_TAB_COLS TCP ON TCP.TABLE_NAME = RCC.TABLE_NAME AND TCP.COLUMN_NAME = RCC.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE TCF.DATA_TYPE || '(' || TCF.DATA_PRECISION || ',' || TCF.DATA_SCALE || ')' != TCP.DATA_TYPE || '(' || TCP.DATA_PRECISION || ',' || TCP.DATA_SCALE || ')'
ORDER BY c.constraint_name, cc.table_name, cc.position;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (checks one schema):

```
select mcols.table_name , mcols.column_name, mcols.data_type, mcols.data_length, mcols.data_precision, mcols.data_scale, dcols.table_name, dcols.column_name, dcols.data_length, dcols.data_precision, dcols.data_scale
from user_tab_cols mcols, user_cons_columns mc, user_constraints dt, user_cons_columns dc, user_tab_cols dcols
where dt.constraint_type = 'R'  -- Referential constraints, i.e. foreign keys
and dt.r_constraint_name = mc.constraint_name
and dc.constraint_name = dt.constraint_name
and mc.position = dc.position
and mcols.table_name = mc.table_name
and mcols.column_name = mc.column_name
and dcols.table_name = dc.table_name
and dcols.column_name = dc.column_name
-- Filter to list only columns that differ
and (mcols.data_type <> dcols.data_type      -- Check for CHAR vs VARCHAR2
  or mcols.data_length <> dcols.data_length  -- Check length (for varchar columns)
  or nvl(mcols.data_precision, 0) <> nvl(dcols.data_precision, 0) -- Check precision (for number columns)
  or nvl(mcols.data_scale, 0) <> nvl(dcols.data_scale, 0)  -- Check scale (for number columns)
);
;
```